# Convenient way to switch between "hot reload" and "live reload" while developing in React?

Tags: reactjs

I recently made a new React app while following the instructions on their installation page: https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html.

This involves using Node to build a project like so:

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

I have noticed after running this app, that the default reload behaviour after making a change in the code, is a "hot-reload", where it only refreshes the file in which the code changed. However, I am also interested in sometimes using "live-reload" as well, where the whole app is refreshed.

Does anyone know of a convenient way to switch between "hot" and "live" reload methods during development?

Comment: Perhaps I used the wrong tags for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the main issue I was having was the console not being cleared on a hot reload, I decided the below workaround is probably better overall.

Just add this to your index.js...

```
window.addEventListener('message', e => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && e.data && e.data.type === 'webpackInvalid') {
        console.clear();
    }
});
```

...and this will make your console clear on a hot-reload.